# Waiting Paradox problem

Tags: probability, distributions

Can you help with this task?

Buses A and B arrive independently. Man comes to a busstop in random time and seat in first bus (he can seat in both bus, A or B). How much time in average he have to wait?

a) Bus A arrives every 10 mins. Bus B arrives every 15 mins. 
b) Time between 2 same buses are distributed exponentially, with expectancy 10 and 15 mins.

Comment: Welcome. Please take 'tour'--especially the parts about asking a good question and how to handle 'textbook style' questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the distribution of the minimum of
two independent exponential distributions. 
If you use the CDF method, you will find that the minimum is exponential with the sum of the two
rates.

In R, the exponential distribution is parameterized by the rate $\lambda = 1/\mu$ instead of the mean $\mu.$ Here is a relevant simulation using R:

```
set.seed(2020)
a = rexp(10^6, 1/10);  b = rexp(10^6, 1/15)
first = pmin(a,b)  # exponential w/ rate 1/10 + 1/15
mean(first)
[1] 6.001617       # aprx E(min(A,B)) = 6
1/(1/10 + 1/15) 
[1] 6

hdr = "Dist'n of min(A,B) ~ EXP(rate=1/6)"
hist(first, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
  curve(dexp(x, 1/6), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

*Note:* For an analytic solution start as
follows:  Let $X = \min(A, B).$ Then

$$1 - F_X(x) = P(X > x) = P(A > x, B > x)\\
= P(A > x)P(B > x) = \cdots = e^{-x/6}.$$